# Is there any way to burn an EOA?

Tags: contract-invocation, eoa

I have a non-upgradeable contract that gives an EOA the non-revokable permission to pause certain actions in the contract. I inherited from OpenZeppelin's [PausableRole.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.5.1/contracts/access/roles/PauserRole.sol) but I removed the "renouncePauser" function.

My question: is there any way to effectively "burn" the EOA? That is, to get it into a state in which it  can't send txs anymore, or at least can't send txs to this specific contract.

I know that this is probably impossible, but I thought to ask the question anyways. Maybe it is possible to use CREATE2 and mine a contract at the exact specific address, which doesn't have the ability to ping the pausable contract?